# Propriedade font-stretch

Tags: html, css, css3, font

Hoje deparei-me com uma propriedade CSS bastante intrigante que é o `font-stretch`.

No Google Chrome normalmente quando inspecionamos um elemento que tem várias propriedades juntas numa só propriedade (por exemplo: `margin:► 0; font:► 14px sans-serif; border:► 1px solid #000;`), elas aparecem com uma **setinha** como eu adicionei nestes exemplos acima, onde podemos clicar nela para estender o conteúdo e vermos quais são as propriedades que estão a ser aplicadas adicionando o código desta maneira.

Neste caso quando cliquei na seta para estender o `font:► 16px sans-serif;`, eu encontrei a propriedade `font-stretch`, que eu desconhecia:

```
.sidebar h2, .widget h2.title {
    color: #333;
    font:▼ 16px sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-stretch: normal;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: normal;
      font-family: Oswald;
    padding:► 5px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Então eu fiz uma pesquisa no Google, e tal e qual como eu suspeitei e como o próprio nome indica, esta propriedade serve para esticar e encolher texto. Mas agora aqui é que está a cena... Nenhum (ou quase nenhum) navegador suporta esta propriedade, de acordo com o: [w3schools - font-stretch Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-stretch.asp)

[image: tabela de supurte]

Então para que serve a propriedade `font-stretch`? Qual é a sua finalidade?
Será que ela foi uma propriedade implementada já a pensar no futuro e por isso ela ainda não se encontra em funcionamento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faz o que você entendeu mesmo. E ela está implementada em alguns navegadores. Não confie na W3Schools. Um local mais confiável para descobrir isto é o [`caniuse.com`](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-stretch). Ele não é 100% confiável, mas é quase. Ele mostra já existir no IE, Edge e FireFox. Acho que logo terá em outros já que faz parte da [especificação](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-stretch-prop) do CSS 3 como *Candidate Recommendation*.

Para reproduzir o efeito pode fazer isto:

```
span.stretch {
    display:inline-block;
    transform:scale(2,1); /* W3C */
    -webkit-transform:scale(2,1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(2,1); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(2,1); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(2,1); /* Opera */
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/BrowserDependent.css).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12065925/221800).

[Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-stretch).